Vue 3 and Amplify UI - logout function called multiple times
I am using latest version of Amplify and Vue3 with Vite. Here are the dependencies from package.json file:
"dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/ui-vue": "^4.2.16",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^5.2.10",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.17.7",
    "@types/vue-select": "^3.16.8",
    "@vuepic/vue-datepicker": "^9.0.3",
    "@vueuse/core": "^11.1.0",
    "aws-amplify": "^6.6.2",
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "chart.js": "^4.4.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "pinia": "^2.2.2",
    "v-idle": "^1.0.3",
    "vue": "^3.4.37",
    "vue-chartjs": "^5.3.1",
    "vue-i18n": "^10.0.1",
    "vue-router": "^4.4.5",
    "vue-select": "^4.0.0-beta.6",
    "vue-toastification": "^2.0.0-rc.5",
    "vuedraggable": "^4.1.0"
  },

The <authenticator> component from @aws-amplify/ui-vue is used to display the login form like so:

Whenever I'm calling the logout() function (by clicking a link) the front-end makes a request to /api/admin/authentication/logout endpoint to write a log (in the back-end) that the user has logged out:
// TopNav.vue
<template>
   <a href="/logout" class="nav-link" role="button" @click.prevent="logout">{{ $t('logout') }}</a>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import { signOut } from 'aws-amplify/auth'
...
// Functions
const logout = async (): Promise<void> => {
  await signOut()
}

In the App.vue file I have this:
<template>
  <authenticator :login-mechanisms="['email']" hide-sign-up>
    <template v-slot:default>
      <div>
        <header>
          <nav-bar />
          <top-nav />
        </header>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <router-view />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
  </authenticator>
  <app-footer :progress="progress" />
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onBeforeMount, onUnmounted } from 'vue'
import { Authenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-vue'
import { fetchAuthSession } from '@aws-amplify/auth'
import { Hub } from 'aws-amplify/utils'
...
import useApp from './composables/use-app'
import useUser from './composables/use-user'
import { useAuthStore } from './stores/auth'
import router from './router'
// Composables
const authStore = useAuthStore()
const { fetchResources, progress } = useApp()
const { homeRoute } = useUser()
// Functions
const onSignedIn = async (): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    const session = await fetchAuthSession()
    if (session.tokens) {
      await authStore.signIn(session)
      await fetchResources()
      await router.push({ name: homeRoute() })
    }
  } catch(e) {
    // Do nothing
  }
}
const onSignedOut = async (): Promise<void> => {
  await authStore.signOut()
  await router.push('/')
}
onBeforeMount(async () => {
  Hub.listen('auth', async (data): Promise<void> => {
    const { payload } = data
    switch(payload.event) {
      case 'signedIn':
        await onSignedIn()
        break
      case 'signedOut':
        await onSignedOut()
        break
    }
  })
  await onSignedIn()
})
onUnmounted(() => {
  Hub.listen('auth', () => {})
})
</script>

Here's the stores/auth.ts file:
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { AuthSession } from 'aws-amplify/auth'
import http from '../services/http'
import type { IUser } from '../types'
export const useAuthStore = defineStore({
  id: 'auth',
  state: () => ({
    accessToken: '',
    idToken: '',
    refreshToken: '',
    user: {} as IUser
  }),
  actions: {
    setAccessToken(token: string): void {
      this.accessToken = token
    },
    setIdToken(token: string): void {
      this.idToken = token
    },
    setRefreshToken(token: string): void {
      this.refreshToken = token
    },
    setUser(user: IUser): void {
      this.user = user
    },
    async signIn(session: AuthSession, silent: boolean = false): Promise<boolean> {
      if (session.tokens?.accessToken) {
        this.setAccessToken(session.tokens?.accessToken.toString())
      }
      if (session.tokens?.idToken) {
        this.setIdToken(session.tokens.idToken.toString())
        if (! silent) {
          await http.post('/admin/authentication/login', {
            token: this.getIdToken
          })
          const response = await http.get('/admin/users/current')
          if (response.data.data) {
            this.setUser(response.data.data)
          }
        }
        return true
      }
      return false
    },
    async signOut(): Promise<void> {
      await http.post('/admin/authentication/logout')
      this.setAccessToken('')
      this.setIdToken('')
      this.setUser({} as IUser)
    },
  },
  getters: {
    getAccessToken(state): string {
      return state.accessToken
    },
    getIdToken(state): string {
      return state.idToken
    },
    getRefreshToken(state): string {
      return state.refreshToken
    },
    getUser(state): IUser {
      return state.user
    }
  }
})

It turns out that logout() function mentioned earlier is called multiple times and the API is pinged multiple times resulting in duplicate entry logs. How can I make sure that logout() function's API call to /admin/authentication/logout is triggered only once?
